# Suppose that $f(0) = 0, \forall x \in (0, 1]: f(x) > 0$ and the right-hand derivative $f'_{+}(0)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. 
> Suppose that $f(0) = 0, \forall x \in (0, 1]: f(x) > 0$ and the right-hand derivative $f'_{+}(0)$ exists.

I'm trying to prove that the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{f(x)} dx$ does not exist.
I struggle to interpret the assumptions, I took some examples but I'm not sure how I can relate $\frac{1}{f}$ to $f$ directly.

I'd like to have some guidance, thanks

Comment: Fixing an $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in[0,\delta)$ you have $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}<f'(0)+\epsilon$. You can use this inequality to bound $1/f$ from below, at least in the interval $[0,\delta)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a:=f'_+(0)$ and $b:=|a|+1$ (actually, $a\ge0$ but we shall not use it).

By the assumptions,
$$\forall x\in(0,1]\quad 0<f(x)=x\left(a+\varepsilon(x)\right)$$
for some function $\varepsilon$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\varepsilon(x)=0.$

Therefore, for $x>0$ close enough to $0,$
$$0<f(x)\le bx$$
hence
$$\frac1{f(x)}\ge\frac1{bx},$$
which makes your improper integral equal to $+\infty.$

Comment: Nice answer (+1).

Comment: So the continuity of $f$ at $(0, 1]$ is only necessary to deduce $\frac{1}{f}$ is integrable at  $[\delta, 1]$ where $\delta \in (0,1)$? If so can we instead assume, for example, $\frac{1}{f}$ is integrable at any interval $[\delta, 1]$ and $f$ is integrable at $[0,1]$?

Comment: The integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$ is even useless. We only need $1/f$ integrable on any interval $[\delta,1],$ and $f>0$ on $(0,1],$ $f(0)=0,$ and $f'_+(0)$ exists.

Comment: @AnneBauval So the existence of such $\varepsilon(x)$ is the main idea and equivalent to the assumptions $f > 0$ on $(0,1], f(0) = 0, f'_{+}(0)$ exists, right? Can we come up with similar assumptions at the case where the improper integral is $\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f}dx$? Thanks

Comment: 1) Right. 2) $f>0$ on $(a,\infty],$ $f(a)=0,$ $f'_+(a)$ exists.